# Reset of PCH when adding a value to PCL using addwf pic18f2x

Tags: assembly, pic, program-counter

I'm trying to use simple lookup tables in assembly by adding a certain index to the program counter. It appears to be working in a range of the `PCL` (so until `0xff`) but afterwards, when the `PCH` comes in to play the `PCH` just resets after the `addwf` instruction.

How do I prevent the `PCH` from resetting after addition? Do I need to manipulate the `PCLATH` and `PCLATU` in some way so `PCH` will keep its value.

*I'm using a pic18f25k50 with the mpasm assembler.*

So this lookup table works fine:

```
TABLE_GET_VALUE
    movf    index, 0 ; memory location = 0x9E 
    mullw   4
    movf    PRODL, 0
    addwf   PC
    movf    0x20, 0
    return
    movf    0x21, 0
    return
    movf    0x22, 0
    return
    movf    0x23, 0
    return
    movf    0x24, 0
    return
    movf    0x25, 0
    return
    movf    0x26, 0
    return
    movf    0x27, 0
    return
    movf    0x28, 0
    return      ; memory location = 0xC8
```

while this one resets the program back to the first instructions:

```
TABLE_GET_COEFFICIENT
    movf    index, 0    ; memory location 0x108
    mullw   4
    movf    PRODL, 0
    addwf   PC
    movf    0x30, 0
    return
    movf    0x31, 0
    return
    movf    0x32, 0
    return
    movf    0x33, 0
    return
    movf    0x34, 0
    return
    movf    0x35, 0
    return
    movf    0x36, 0
    return
    movf    0x37, 0
    return
    movf    0x38, 0
    return      ; memory location 0x132
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is one example of a complete way to code the table look up for a PIC18F controller.

```
;------------------------------------------------------------------------------ 
; MAIN PROGRAM 
;------------------------------------------------------------------------------ 
MAIN_CODE CODE              ; let linker place main program 

Main: 
    movlw   8
    call    TableOneLookup
    bra     Main

;------------------------------------------------------------------------------ 
;
; TableOneLookup
;
; Description: Look up data in table placed in code space
;
; Input:  WREG = byte offset in table
;
; Output: WREG = byte from table
;
;------------------------------------------------------------------------------ 
TABLE_ONE_CODE  code
TableOneLookup:
    push
    clrf    TOSU
    clrf    TOSH
    movwf   TOSL                ; Save offset in to TableOne
    addwf   TOSL,F              ; Double offset in to TableOne
    rlcf    TOSH,F              ; Propagate carry
    movlw   LOW(TabelOne)       ; Add TableOne address low byte
    addwf   TOSL,F
    movlw   HIGH(TabelOne)      ; Add TableOne address high byte
    addwfc  TOSH,F
    movlw   UPPER(TabelOne)     ; Add TableOne address upper byte
    addwfc  TOSU,F
    return                      ; Branch in to TableOne
TabelOne:
    DT      0x30
    DT      0x31
    DT      0x32
    DT      0x33
    DT      0x34
    DT      0x35
    DT      0x36
    DT      0x37
    DT      0x38
    end
```

There are better ways to do this using the assembly language opcodes specifically designed for program memory read operations.

Answer (score 0):

So I found the answer.

Apparently when you write to the `PCL` the `PCLATH` and `PCLATU` 's content is written directly to the `PCH` and `PCU`. This means the latches are never updated with the current value in this process. A way to update the `PCLATH` and `PCLATU` is by reading the `PCL`. This triggers the latches to update to the current value which means when writing to `PCL` later the wright value is copied in.

Like so:

```
TABLE_GET_COEFFICIENT
    movf    index, 0    ; memory location 0x108
    mullw   4
    movf    PC, 0       ; writing te PC value just for updating latches
    movf    PRODL, 0
    addwf   PC
    movf    0x30, 0
    return
    movf    0x31, 0
    return
    movf    0x32, 0
    return
    movf    0x33, 0
    return
    movf    0x34, 0
    return
    movf    0x35, 0
    return
    movf    0x36, 0
    return
    movf    0x37, 0
    return
    movf    0x38, 0
    return      ; memory location 0x132
```

more info in the data sheet: 3.1.1 and 5.1.1